# I have some issue with jquery css method

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the color of the button when it is clicked using this code

```
$('.vote').click(function(){
  var self = $(this);
  var type = $(this).data("type");
  var action = $(this).data("action");
  var parent = self.parent();
  if(!(status == '1')){
    if(type == '1'){
      self.css("color","orange");
    }
    else if(type == '2'){
      self.css("color":"red"});
    }
  }
});
```

And it is not working. But when I try to put this line `self.css("color","orange");` outside the IF statement it is working :

```
$('.vote').click(function(){
  var self = $(this);
  var type = $(this).data("type");
  var action = $(this).data("action");
  var parent = self.parent();
  self.css("color","orange");
  if(!(status == '1')){
    if(type == '1'){
      //if statement here
    }
    else if(type == '2'){
      //if statement here
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is that it is not what I want to happen. How can I make it happen using the first code above.

Comment: My guess is either status does equal one or type does not equal 1.

Comment: Looks like your issue is not with the jQuery css method, but your conditional logic (if statements) make sure 'type' and 'status' are what you expect them to be

Comment: it is my fault... I didn't notice that i changed the type from 1 and 2 to 'up' and 'down'. So thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appear to be in the following line :

```
self.css("color":"red"});
```

You've missed to open bracket `{` here :

```
self.css({"color":"red"});
_________^
```

Or just use comma `,` as you do in first example :

```
self.css("color","red");
```

Hope this helps.

```js
 var status = '2';

$('.vote').click(function(){
  var self = $(this);
  var type = $(this).data("type");
  var action = $(this).data("action");
  var parent = self.parent();

  if(!(status == '1')){
    if(type == '1'){
      self.css("color","orange");
    }
    else if(type == '2'){
      self.css({"color":"red"});
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='vote' data-type='1'>Vote type 1</button>
<button class='vote' data-type='2'>Vote type 2</button>
```

Comment: thanks I think I found the problem myself... it is in html part, but I think I would not notice without your suggestion so thanks